# Copy data from other database vs direct querying it SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

There are 2 databases in the server

1st Database contains fresh updated data from all employees in the company and rarely goes offline unless server goes down.

2nd Database only reads employee number and name and if is active. There are no inserts or updates.

All data on 2nd Database is copied from 1st with a Job everyday

I would like to know what are the cons of accessing it with a join directly instead of replicating all the data

Comment: Is the other database taken offline periodically for maintenance? Or is there a concern the application you are tasked with maintaining adversely affecting the other database? Also, if the application if "full of bugs" perhaps the previous developer was a little lacking in SQL knowledge and didn't know you could join tables in separate databases. All speculation.

Comment: Both databases are running all the time, the application only fetches the employee data, it does not do any crud operation besides reading

Comment: There is a less than 0% chance anybody can give you an accurate answer here. This is so incredibly vague and would require knowledge of the system far beyond the scope of an online forum. There are many reasons for and against this type of architecture.

Comment: Agree with @SeanLange This isn't a SQL question. It's a question about your specific application you are debugging. I agree it sounds superfluous though...

Comment: updated the topic to be short and clear. please recheck

Comment: If the table is being updated frequently then copying the data into a read only type environment can ease the pressure on locking. This is often done with high volume tables.

Comment: that makes sense but the table doesn't have that much data, it's just a bit over 2k rows

Comment: Doesn't matter how many rows, it is the frequency of changes or the frequency of queries. An update would have to wait for the select statement to finish. And sometimes this delay is unacceptable. Kind of sounds to me like evaluating changing the frequency of data replication might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the 2nd database is a data warehouse, it could help to track all history transactions. While 1st database only contains the most updated data, it's faster to query.

Let's say, you want to know what happens right now, then 1st database is light-weighted and could help you find answers quickly. However, if you want to see what happened before, you couldn't find it in 1st database, then 2nd database is their to look up.

Comment: that would make sense if that was true but it's not a data warehouse, it's just a small application that needs to access up to date data from employees